# How to enable CORS on express.js 4.x on all files?

Tags: node.js, express

I keep receiving

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://example.com:2013/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1433950808025-0.
>   (Reason: CORS request failed).

while I try to access my node.js. This doesn't work for me:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

@edit: here is the updated full code:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var expressvar = express();

expressvar.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.header('origin'));
    next();
});
expressvar.use(express.static('../'));
expressvar.use("/socket.io", express.static('../socket.io'));
var app = http.createServer(expressvar);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
app.listen(2013);
```

Comment: What type of request methods are you trying (POST, GET, ...)? For certain one you might need to enable `OPTIONS`: `app.options('*', function(req, res) { res.status(200).send(); });`

Comment: It didn't help. What I'm doing is trying to include socket.io from different port, and it gives me CORS error.

Comment: what are the response headers in Chrome DevTools network inspector? Does `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header has proper value?

Comment: Chrome DevTools say `example.com:2013/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1435751626920-1`  Status:(failed)  and Firefox says `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: ...` I guess it's something with the socket headers not getting sent, I tried `io.set('origins', '*:*')` and still doesn't work

Comment: Actually I wanted to see the response headers sent by node server. F12 -> Network tab -> F5 -> click on the link and you will see request and response headers.

Comment: the origin is `example.com` (no port 2013) and it says there is no response data

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this solution (edited to include full working code)

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.set('origins', '*:*');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.get('Origin') || '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Length');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Range');
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return res.send(200);
  } else {
    return next();
  }
});

server.listen(80);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('OK');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, though it doesn't work. The socket.io can't be included because of the CORS error. How do I set headers there?

Comment: Just added a more complete solution. Seems to be working here with Express 4

Comment: I think the problem is that the socket.io file is sent through port 2013 and it's getting blocked because apache proxies everything through port 80, but I can't get my head around what should I change

Comment: That's a completely different question! This one resolves the CORS issue.

:)

Comment: Yeah I thought it's related to that, but the more I dug in the code the more I realised that I'm wrong from the beginning... I'll have to ask one more question, this time a proper one, I hope :P

Comment: how about when using https?

Answer (score 8):

[cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package does this

```
// npm install --save cors
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static());
app.get('*', function(){});
require('http').createServer(app).listen(3000)
```

Comment: I've used your code and I still get error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked` :( I must be missing something

Comment: @MateuszBartkowski Wow sounds like you're not alone! https://duckduckgo.com/?q=socket.io+cors&ia=qa

Answer (score 4):

Try using `res.setHeader` instead.

This example works for me:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.header('origin'));

    next();
});
```

Comment: I'm getting `Error: "name" and "value" are required for setHeader().` now :( What I'm doing is trying to include socket.io from different port, and it gives me CORS error
@edit: when I comment out origin header it prints the page but still won't include socket.io because of that error

Comment: that would imply that you have not formatted the arguments correctly. Ensure that you have two string values separated by a comma. Failing that, post what your code looks like now in the OP

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble with this for quite a while do you have an app.configure function? If so this is what ended up working for me.

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.set('port', 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.urlencoded());
  app.use(express.json());
  app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
  });
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the socket.io file is sent through port 2013 and it's getting blocked because apache proxies everything through port 80, but I can't get my head around what should I change

Answer (score 0):

Inside your app.js add this lines of code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(9081);

app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
    origin = req.get('Origin') || '*';
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    res.set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Length');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type'); // add the list of headers your site allows.
if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) return res.send(200);
    next();
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the socket.io file is sent through port 2013 and it's getting blocked because apache proxies everything through port 80, but I can't get my head around what should I change.

Comment: @MateuszBartkowski   This is tested code. Please try this one. Use any other port other than 80.

Comment: Error for port 80 is like Error: listen EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1112:19)
    at listen (net.js:1155:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1240:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/santanu/Projects/temp/app.js:7:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)